Is it okay to post the text of a book being asked about in a question?
I'm learning Haskell using the book Thinking Functionally with Haskell. At times I've felt that some of the text is not very clear and the example a little too complex. Is it okay if I post the text of the book verbatim? I'm not sure if doing that will infringe on the copyright.

How would that help?

For any questions regarding the copyright of a book, you'd really need to ask a lawyer (if you think it's fair use) or the copyright holder. There's nothing Stack Overflow specific about sharing content from a copyrighted work.

But of course anything you do post that wasn't written by you should be properly attributed.

“Is it okay if I post the text of the book verbatim?” - Just copying and pasting someone’s else work is called plagiarism. If you copy and paste their work, quote and cite it, and include your own summary then it most likely will not be treated as plagiarism. It entirely depends if your summary answers the question or not.

@SecurityHound While your comment is accurate, it's worth noting that copyright and plagiarism are largely orthogonal issues. It's possible to plagiarize without violating copyright, as well as to violate copyright without plagiarizing.

I would think that it is besides the point. You will be going to ask a pretty unresearched question if the question is going to be about not understanding what one piece of reference material says. Consult a second one then. Or a third. The question which is fit for Stack Overflow would be able to highlight multiple sources that you consulted and collectively did not understand.
